# Meta field for Domain Url? Or is it possible to change the index of google?

Tags: metadata

So I did the misstake of using a temporary url a while ago when launching my web site and called it http://web.mysite.com

Now when google indexes it, even that the web. is not the primary url anymore it still uses that over the http://www.mysite.com

Is there any way I can change this? Unfortunately I cant remove the web.mysite.dom binding from IIS since all Google links refer to that and I cannot use wildcard binding on the actual server.

I have google analytics enabled with the correct url (www.mysite.com).

Is there a way to enter some kind of meta data that enforces the robots to see the address as www.mysite.com?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did resolve by creating the web.mysite.com and put a permanent redirect www.mysite.com (301). Also used google webmaster tools to ensure this was correctly done.